# facing error when insert custom _id in cloudant document?

Tags: android, database, couchdb, cloudant

When I don't set the `_id` I can insert a document, however, when I add `_id` then I receive an error:

```
Failed to create document java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
   com.cloudant.sync.datastore.InvalidDocumentException: Field name start
   with '_' is not allowed.
```

My code is:

```
private Map<String, String> temponload() {
    Map<String, String> userInfo = new HashMap<>();
    userInfo.put("_id", "org:HELLO"+str_email);
    userInfo.put("first_name", "FIRSTNAME");
    userInfo.put("last_name", "LASTNAME");

    return userInfo;
}
public Map<String, String> createDocument(Map<String, String> map) {
    DocumentRevision rev = new DocumentRevision();
    rev.setBody(DocumentBodyFactory.create(map));
    try {
        DocumentRevision created = sunDatastore.createDocumentFromRevision(rev);
        return map;
    } catch (DocumentException de) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Please help me for this issue

Comment: You can use `_` in middle of column name but not in start. like id_map etc.

Comment: no i need to use in starting like "_id" this only. in cloudant document it use like this only

Answer (score 1):

`_` prefixed fields in CouchDB/Cloudant are meta-data fields.

In the library you are using ([sync-android on github](https://github.com/cloudant/sync-android)), meta-data fields are accessed via getters on the `DocumentRevision` object itself and the document body is rejected if if it has `_` prefixed fields.

The meta-data fields are:

- _id
- _rev
- _deleted

To set the ID for the document you **must** use the constructor as per Chris Snow's answer. If the ID is not set for a document the library will
generate an ID for that document, which is why it successfully saves if you omit the `_id` from the body of the document.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the constructor where you pass in the Id to DocumentRevision, i.e.

```
DocumentRevision(java.lang.String id)
```

**Source**: http://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.cloudant/cloudant-sync-datastore-javase/1.1.5